# Cannot find a valid baseurl for any repo in centos 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, shell, centos6

when I want to install any repo I found this error

```
 Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free
```

I'm using centos 6.4

I tried to check other packages I found the same error ... so it's not on specific pacakge .. (i.e PostgreSQL)

yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-libs

here is my rpmfusion-free.repo

```
[rpmfusion-free]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch

[rpmfusion-free-debuginfo]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free - Debug
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-debug-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch

[rpmfusion-free-source]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Free - Source
#baseurl=http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-source-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-$releasever-$basearch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paste the rpmfusion.repo (or whatever) file from your /etc/yum.repos.d directory. That being said that error either means the file is incomplete or the mirrorurl that is configured is broken (i.e. not returning any values) or no longer exists (assuming yum wouldn't give a different error for either of those conditions).

Given the contents of that file it appears as if you have misconfigured the repo. You can see this by trying to load `http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-fedora-6&arch=i386` in your browser and inspecting the output. Notice the error indication and the fact that all lines are commented out. You need to adjust the mirrorlist entries in those repository configuration blocks to match your system. You probably want to use something like `http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=free-el-6&arch=i386` and friends.

Comment: updated  with rpmfusion-free.repo

Comment: that's all files about rpmfusion
rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo          rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide.repo
rpmfusion-free.repo, rpmfusion-nonfree.repo,rpmfusion-free-updates.repo,rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo,rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo,  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo

Comment: Where did you get these repo files from? Did you install a package which added them? If you did then it appears you installed a package for the wrong distribution. If you created them by hand (or copied them from somewhere) you also used the wrong distribution version but in that case you should be able to just edit them in place (as opposed to removing the wrong package and installing the correct one).

Comment: yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-libs ... that's an example of what I want to install ... it's for centos 6.4 .. so nothing created by hand :). I tried to install  postgresql from other mirros but the same error raise

Comment: Not what you are trying to install now. I was discussing how you got your rpmfusion.repo files in the first place. They aren't part of CentOS itself. You (or someone else) had to add them to the system.

Comment: You will need to correct or remove those repositories configuration entries (or temporarily disable them with `--disablerepo='rpmfusion-*'` when running yum) for yum to work correctly.

Comment: OK I got it .. So Kindly if I need to add them so what I should look for ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9656/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-maged-mohammed)

Comment: it's work now when I disabled them temp. 
thank you